# how to setup facebook account kit in flutter app

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter, account-kit

I want to setup facebook account kit in my flutter app.
Facebook official developer site only has Android, iOS and Javascript SDKs.
Is it possible to setup facebook account kit in a flutter app? 
I have tried to search google a lot but found nothing useful.
If its possible then please show me a way of doing that
TIA.

Comment: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_account_kit

Answer (score 1):

You can use this library for use FB account kit with flutter application Which makes easy to integrate FB account Kit in Flutter Applications.
[https://github.com/peerwaya/flutter_account_kit](http://github.com/peerwaya/flutter_account_kit)